# is the Louvain method used in networkx take edge weight in account？

Tags: social-networking

I'm using networkX to do some community detection. I wonder if there is a method for community detection can take the weight of edge into account?
I've used the Louvain Method in Gephi, but the result shows me it hasn't refer to edge weight, I want to know if the Louvain Method in networkX can use edge weight?

Comment: How did you reach this conclusion about Gephi? I am not an expert in intrepreting the results of the Louvain method however Gephi has this checkbox that enables the use of weights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Sometimes there is small differences in networkx or the algorithm about which python object property is used as weight, but managing weighting graph is one of the fundamental principles of the algorithm (at least after the first level of recursion).